# How can i manage asynchronous queries on Mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

How can i manage please asynchronous callback on Node Js and MongoDb. My for loop is working. This is my code :

```
  User.count( function(err, count){
    console.log('counting'+ count);

    for(let nbUsersWithTeams=0; nbUsersWithTeams<count; nbUsersWithTeams=nbUsersWithTeams+6){
        Team.create({},
            function(err, team){
                if(err) return res.boom.badImplementation(err);
                console.log('The id of the new team is', team._id)

                /*Team.findOne({_id: team._id }).exec( 
                    function(err, team){
                        if(err) return res.boom.badImplementation(err);
                        this.newTeam=team;
                    }
                ); */
                i=0;
                for(let i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++){

                        User.distinct( "_id" ).exec(function( err, result) {
                            if (err) return res.boom.badImplementation(err.message);

                            var randomId = result[Math.floor(Math.random() * (count-1))];

                            User.findOne({_id: randomId}).exec(
                                function( err, user) {
                                    if (err) return res.boom.badImplementation(err.message);

                                    user.team=team._id;
                                    user.save( function(err) {
                                        if (err) return res.boom.badImplementation(err.message);
                                        console.log('nb users in teams so far'+nbUsersWithTeams);
                                        console.log('the i is'+ i);
                                        console.log('push');
                                        team.members.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id));
                                        team.save(function(err) {
                                            if (err) return res.boom.badImplementation(err.message);
                                        });

                                    });
                                    //nbUsersWithTeams=nbUsersWithTeams+1;

                                }
                            );
                        });                  
                }               
        });
    }
  });
```

I want to put on each of my teams 12 people exactly but i get more people in it.I think it's due to asynchronous callback from mongoDb.

Here are the schemas :

For the User:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  email : {
   type: Schema.Types.String, required: true
  },
  displayName : {
   type: Schema.Types.String, required: true
  },
  team : {
   ref : 'Team',
   type : Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  picture : { /// url picture
  type : Schema.Types.String
  },
  piecesVersionGamer : [
  {
    piece : {
    ref:'Piece',
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  date : {
    type : Schema.Types.Date, default: Date.now
    }
   }
 ],
badges: [
  {
  photoPuzzle : {
    ref: 'PhotoPuzzle',
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  date : {
    type : Schema.Types.Date, default : Date.now
  }
}
```

]);

And for the Team :

```
export class Team{
 _id : any;
 photoPuzzle : string;
 piecesNotFound : string[];
 members : string[];

}
```

Comment: Hard to follow without the schema definitions. I can see the user has a team and a team has many users.

Comment: I added the schemas